# SYNPROXY doesn't seem to be running

Tags: iptables, flooding, syn

I have attempted to create `iptables` rules to prevent my server connections limit to be filled up with in-completed SYN packets for which no ACK packet is returned by the client (SYN flood attack).

I have read the [RFC 4987 TCP SYN Flooding Attacks and Common Mitigations][1] and [Mitigate TCP SYN Flood Attacks with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Beta][2] and finally tried to follow the instructions [here][3]: https://javapipe.com/blog/iptables-ddos-protection/

However, my site is still easily taken down with a DOS attack using the following command:

```
hping -S --flood -V -p 443 www.mydomain.com
```

At the end of the tutorial from Javapipe.com linked above, the command is mentioned to tell whether SYNPROXY is active or not.

> To verify that SYNPROXY is working, you can do watch -n1 cat
>   /proc/net/stat/synproxy. If the values change when you establish a new
>   TCP connection to the port you use SYNPROXY on, it works.

The command is:

```
watch -n1 cat /proc/net/stat/synproxy
```

When I use that command on my server and try to load a page, the data does not change and is all zeros.

```
Every 1.0s: cat /proc/net/stat/synproxy                                                                                                      Thu Jul 25 19:57:00 2019

entries         syn_received    cookie_invalid  cookie_valid    cookie_retrans  conn_reopened
00000000        00000000        00000000        00000000        00000000        00000000
```

Here is the output of iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             #conn src/32 > 80 reject-with tcp-reset
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW limit: avg 20/sec burst 20
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:RST/RST limit: avg 2/sec burst 2
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:RST/RST
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
SYNPROXY   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp ctstate INVALID,UNTRACKED SYNPROXY sack-perm timestamp wscale 7 mss 1460 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_public  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_public (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_public_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_public_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_public_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

The server is a VPS with Digital Ocean running Centos 7.6, Kernel: 3.10.0-862.2.3.el7.x86_64

Can anyone help explain why SYNPROXY may not be running, or else, why / how to protect my server from SYN flooding?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your server? Is it a dedicated box, a virtual machine, what version of Linux kernel, what version of your Linux distribution, output of `iptables -l`, etc?

Comment: I have added those things to the OP just now.  You may notice that I have altered some of the rules from Javapipe tutorial, but the posted info are the current rules.